# How to join absolute and relative urls?

Tags: python, url

I have two urls:

```
url1 = "http://127.0.0.1/test1/test2/test3/test5.xml"
url2 = "../../test4/test6.xml"
```

How can I get an absolute url for url2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join components of a path when you are constructing a URL in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793261/how-to-join-components-of-a-path-when-you-are-constructing-a-url-in-python)

Comment: Related: [Joining url path components intelligently](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13027/joining-url-path-components-intelligently)

Answer (score 318, accepted):

You should use [urlparse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) :

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin(url1, url2)
'http://127.0.0.1/test1/test4/test6.xml'
```

With Python 3 (where [urlparse is renamed to urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#index-0)) you could [use it as follow](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin(url1, url2)
'http://127.0.0.1/test1/test4/test6.xml'
```

Comment: How we use `urljoin` with 3 or mode parameters or which library do you recommend for this?

Comment: @mesuutt try to make a loop and join each part with the previously joined URL.

Comment: @CédricJulien: a simple loop will not work, as any path with a leading `/` will "reset" and return scheme + netloc + lasturl: `urlparse.urljoin('http://www.a.com/b/c/d', '/e')  => 'http://www.a.com/e'`

Comment: If using the urljoin, there's a problem. For example,  `urljoin('http://www.a.com/', '../../b/c.png')`, the result is `'http://www.a.com/../../b/c.png'`, but not `http://www.a.com/b/c.png`. So, is there any method to get `http://www.a.com/b/c.png`?

Comment: Link to Python 3 documentation points to Python 2 documentation, it needs to updated in the answer, it is https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin

Comment: For `urljoin` with 3 or more parts, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54217907/319397

Comment: @bigwind — In last Python version (I tested with 3.8) `urljoin` works correctly with your case

Answer (score 23):

If your relative path consists of multiple parts, you have to join them separately, since `urljoin` would replace the relative path, not join it. The easiest way to do that is to use `posixpath`.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> import posixpath
>>> url1 = "http://127.0.0.1"
>>> url2 = "test1"
>>> url3 = "test2"
>>> url4 = "test3"
>>> url5 = "test5.xml"
>>> url_path = posixpath.join(url2, url3, url4, url5)
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin(url1, url_path)
'http://127.0.0.1/test1/test2/test3/test5.xml'
```

See also: [How to join components of a path when you are constructing a URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793261/how-to-join-components-of-a-path-when-you-are-constructing-a-url-in-python)

Answer (score 16):

For python 3.0+ the correct way to join urls is:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
urljoin('https://10.66.0.200/', '/api/org')
# output : 'https://10.66.0.200/api/org'
```

Comment: This is limited to join only two path components. Cannot be easily used if there is more.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `reduce` to achieve Shikhar's method in a cleaner fashion.

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(urllib.parse.urljoin, ["http://moc.com/", "path1/", "path2/", "path3/"])
'http://moc.com/path1/path2/path3/'
```

Note that with this method each fragment should have trailing forward-slash, with no leading forward-slash, to indicate it is a path fragment being joined.

This is more correct/informative, telling you that `path1/` is a URI path fragment, and not the full path (e.g. `/path1/`) or an unknown (e.g. `path1`). An unknown could be either, but they are handled as a full path.

If you need to add `/` to a fragment lacking it, you could do:

```py
uri = uri if uri.endswith("/") else f"{uri}/"
```

To learn more about URI resolution, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Resolution) has some nice examples.

**Updates**

- Just noticed Peter Perron commented about reduce on Shikhar's answer, but I'll leave this here then to demonstrate how that's done.
- Updated wikipedia URL

Answer (score 11):

```
es = ['http://127.0.0.1', 'test1', 'test4', 'test6.xml']
base = ''
map(lambda e: urlparse.urljoin(base, e), es)
```

Comment: Good way to support a list of values.
You can remove your side effect (your "base" variable) by using a reduce though.
`reduce(lambda a, b: urlparse.urljoin(a, b), es)`

A map is `list[n] - to -> list[n]`
A reduce is `list[n] - to -> a calculated value`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> url1 = "http://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy"
>>> url2 = "/user/khanacademy"
>>> urljoin(url1, url2)
'http://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy'
```

Simple.