# Join absolute and relative URLs in R

Tags: r, url

I have an absolute URL and a relative URL that I would like to join (like `urljoin` in Python). For the example of [How to join absolute and relative urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223939/how-to-join-absolute-and-relative-urls):

```r
url1 <- "http://127.0.0.1/test1/test2/test3/test5.xml"
url2 <- "../../test4/test6.xml"
```

where `url2` is given with reference to the absolute URL `url1`. How can I get the absolute URL for `url2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `getRelativeURL` function in the `XML` package is designed for this.

```
> library(XML)
> getRelativeURL(url2, url1)
[1] "http://127.0.0.1/test1/test4/test6.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this done in R before but I do know of `file.path`

```
url1 <- "http://127.0.0.1/test1/"
url2 <- "test2/test3/test5.xml"
url3 <- "test4/test6.xml"
file.path(url1, url2)
file.path(url2, url3)
```

If you need something more precise try playing around with the `urltools` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/urltools.pdf