# Problem while checking internal links with BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Answer here : [How to join absolute and relative urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223939/how-to-join-absolute-and-relative-urls/8223955#8223955)

I want to check internal links with BeautifulSoup and Selenium.

Script is working when links are like this : full url path

```
<a href="http...." />
```

Script is NOT working when links are like this : partial url path

```
<a href="/internal_link.php" />
```

My python script :

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'html5lib')
links=[]
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    set="True"
    for word in exc:
        if word in str(link.get('href')).lower():
            set="False"
            break
    if set=="True":
        try:
            st = re.search('(\S+)', str(link.get('href')).lower())
            st = st.group(0)
            if site in st: # 2 SCENARIOS HERE
                links.append(st)
        except:
            pass
```

CASE 1 : check all links: full path

```
if "http" in st:
```

CASE 2 : Check only internal links: (*site* is current page) full path

```
if site in st:
```

So, I'm looking for a way to load links even if there is not the full path of the url

Comment: You join the relative path with the current URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8223955/5386938

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join absolute and relative urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223939/how-to-join-absolute-and-relative-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<a href="/internal_link.php" />
<a href="http://www.example.com/internal_link.php" />
<a href="/internal_link.php" />

'''

exc = ['http']
url = 'http://www.example.com'

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
links=[]
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    for word in exc:
        if word not in str(link.get('href')).lower():
            links.append(''.join([url,link['href']])) 
        if url in str(link.get('href')).lower():
            links.append(link['href']) 
links
```

**Output**

```
['http://www.example.com/internal_link.php',
 'http://www.example.com/internal_link.php',
 'http://www.example.com/internal_link.php']
```