# Is it okay to use os.sep instead of "/" in url

Tags: python, django

It seems to be os.sep returns "/" as a separator, I wonder if I can use that to make a URL:
eg. To get a url like `https://some.domain.com/catalogs`

```
   protocol + request.get_host() + os.sep + get_file_name()
```

- Can this cause any problem? `Or`
- Is there anything in urllib/2 to join uris?

Comment: `os.sep` is OS specific, on Windows it will return `'\'`.

Comment: Why not just use `"/"`?  The URL standard says to use a slash, so use a slash.  os.sep is for dealing with differences among operating systems, but URLs don't have differences like this.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793261/how-to-join-components-of-a-path-when-you-are-constructing-a-url-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.sep` gives you the separator for your current system's file system paths. Your system paths and URI paths aren't the same.

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) gives:

> A path consists of a sequence of path segments separated by a slash
> ("/") character.

If you have an URI like `http://foo.bar.baz/a/b/c/d`, you should use [`urlsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) to split it into components and extract the `path` part. Then you can safely use `.split('/')` to get the individual parts of this path, or use `'/'.join` to construct a path from the segments (if you know that each segment is a valid segment according to the grammar).

The grammar doesn't permit this `/` to be anything other than a separator in the path segment, check the RFC to be doubly sure. This doesn't hold for the whole URL though, `/` will mean different things in other URL sections.

The opposite of `urlsplit` is [`urlunsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit) which can do what you want once you have the path assembled.

To be safe, you should percent-encode the individual path parts before joining them with `/` using `urllib.quote('/test', '')` (mind the second parameter - `/` isn't escaped here by default.)

Answer (score 4):

os.sep will return `\` on Windows - whether that's what you want depends on the protocol you're using I think, but broadly speaking using I think os.sep isn't appropriate for URLs that aren't using `file://` (and even then it's questionable).

You might find `urlparse` useful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: Uniform resource identifier always uses '/', (Specified in the RFC's), and more or less everything network related uses URI, so in practice, _never_ use `os.sep`, unless you are working with filepaths on your system.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation:

> The character used by the operating system to separate pathname
>   components. This is '/' for POSIX and '\' for Windows. Note that
>   knowing this is not sufficient to be able to parse or concatenate
>   pathnames — use os.path.split() and os.path.join() — but it is
>   occasionally useful. Also available via os.path.

So  *No*, it is note safe to use.

For URI parsing, splitting, joining, etc, you should use the [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html) library. (called [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html) in python 2)