# Extracting a link from an href inside another href - nested links (?)

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm not sure I'm asking this question correctly, but I ran into something I've never seen before (FWIW), and since research didn't come up with anything exactly like this, am confused:

Trying to [scrape certain links from this page](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1618732/000161873218000173/ntnx-10312018x10qxq1x19.htm#s37A0BD14ADEA5D06B041171559E11E12). I go through the usual

```
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup =  bs4(html, "lxml")
```

Trying to locate certain links, I do:

```
exh = soup.find_all('a')
```

The output contains a couple of the usual format URLs, but many of them have this form (chosen randomly):

```
exhibit103.htm
```

On the Firefox page, this entry looks like this:

[image]

Note that this entry does not appear clickable, but if you hover over it, [it flashes the actual underlying link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1618732/000161873218000173/exhibit103.htm).

What I consider the relevant part of the html/css for this section looks like this:

```
<td>
  <div>
      <a style="-sec-extract:exhibit;"href="exhibit103.htm">
       <span>Amendment Two [etc.]
           </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</td>
```

It looks to my uninformed eyes like an `href` inside another `href`/nested links. So the general question is - why would anyone bother with this? The more important one (to me) is how do I use BeautifulSoup (or any other method) to extract the actual link?

Comment: Nested links are invalid markup, but the sample you've shown does not contain nested links; just a simple href (with a relative URL).   if it's the relative path that you're asking about, you can [convert that to an absolute url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001007/scrape-the-absolute-url-instead-of-a-relative-path-in-python)

Comment: Wow, they were relative links! For some reason, I didn't think of that possibility. Thanks mucho!

Comment: No trouble, glad to help!