# How to extract a link from a hyperlink from a href tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This isn't just a simple how to retrieve links question. When I scrape a page, the href link returns something like `'/people/4849247002'`, but if you inspect the page itself this href URL actually links to `'https://website/people/4849247002'` if you click it. how can I get the link with `'https://website/people/4849247002'` instead?

also side note, but what's the correct way to use BeautifulSoup to get a webpage? I've been using both of the following:

```py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yourwebsite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
```

and

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

source_code = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'lxml')
```

I'm currently using python 3.8

Comment: What url are you exactly scraping, because right now you're asking three questions, not one.

Comment: https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal this url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrape the absolute URL instead of a relative path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001007/scrape-the-absolute-url-instead-of-a-relative-path-in-python)

Comment: this is kinda the same as me just putting the base URL as a string and doing base + href_link, I was hoping for an answer that could find the same link that you would get if you clicked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req

url = 'https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.listA(url).url) # Print all links
# Or
lstA = doc.selects('a@data-mapped=true>href()')
print ([utils.absoluteUrl(url, a) for a in lstA])
```

Result:

```
['https://adhoc.team/join/', 'https://adhoc.team/blog/', 'https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal/jobs/4877141002', 'https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal/jobs/4877155002', 'https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal/jobs/4869701002', 'https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal/jobs/4877146002', ...
['https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal/jobs/4877141002', 'https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal/jobs/4877155002', ...
```

Or you can use the framework directly.

```
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, SimplifiedMain, utils

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'greenhouse'
    start_urls = ['https://boards.greenhouse.io/adhocexternal']

    def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
        doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
        urls = doc.listA(url.url)
        data = doc.title # Whatever data you want to get
        return {'Urls': urls, 'Data': data}


SimplifiedMain.startThread(MySpider())  # Start download
```

Comment: this gets me the full urls! definitely answers the question. not sure if you could help with this too, but my overall goal is to get URLs only if they're for a specific position. so I would need to search for all divs then collect the URLs within ONLY if the job title is what I'm seeking

Comment: @chadlei Try this: print (doc.listA(url).contains('adhocexternal/jobs/', attr='url').url)

Comment: @chadlei Or: print (doc.listA(url, start='id="filter-count"', end='id="footer"').url)

Comment: how would i implement this if i wanted to put it in my for loop? it looks like this: for div in divs: for link in anchors: if anchor.text has keywords then save the URL (insert your simplified_scrapy line here)

Comment: Do you mean this? lstA = doc.listA(url, start='id="filter-count"', end='id="footer"').url
for a in lstA:
  print (a)

Comment: @chadlei  The comment was not loaded completely just now. lstA = doc.listA(url, start='id="filter-count"', end='id="footer"')
for a in lstA:
  if 'UX' in a.title:
    print (a)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222806/discussion-between-dabingsou-and-chadlei).